# JSCH: No such file error

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I have windows machine with running ssh server. I know the path on that machine. Let it be `D:/Folder1/Folder2`. I'm creating sftp channel using JSCH. But when i try to cd to `D:/Folder1/Folder2`, `"No such file: 2"` error is throwed.

can anyone please help? May be i need to convert path?

Comment: What Windows SSH server? Have you tried it without JSCH (with the sftp program)?

Comment: Well the Cygwin ssh server uses Cygwin paths doesn't it? Like /cygdrive/d/folder1/folder2

Comment: i've tried winscp. executed cd D:/Folder1/Folder2. it cds without any problem.

Comment: I've found the problem in JSCH source code. It looks like some servers unable to handle correctlu real paths. problem in _realpath function. function is throwing status code instead of returning byte array of path

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: Faced this error on Linux where we were mistakenly using an absolute path (starting with `/`); switching it to a relative path (stripping the leading `/`) made the error go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using ChannelExec by opening exec channel. This worked for me. Hope will work for others too.

```
    ...
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

    JSch ssh = new JSch();
    session = ssh.getSession(sshSolrUsername, sshSolrHost, 22);
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.setPassword(sshSolrPassword);
    session.connect();
    channel = session.openChannel("exec");        
    ((ChannelExec)channel ).setCommand("cd " + sourcePath);     
    exec.setInputStream(null);
    ((ChannelExec)channel ).setErrStream(System.err);
    InputStream in = channel .getInputStream();
    channel .connect();
    int status = checkStatus(channel , in);
    channel.disconnect();
    ...
```

Comment: Well, you open shell, execute `cd` and disconnect. What's the point? From your question it looked like you want to use SFTP.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'm using channel to execute other commands. I's just edited piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the path. It is not finding the file to rename, if you are using the JSCH library you can use
channelSftp.pwd ()
to know the current location.

Example:

```
Sftp sftp = new Sftp();
sftp.conectar();
ChannelSftp channelSftp = sftp.getChannelSftp();
channelSftp.rename(channelSftp.pwd()+"//"+file,`channelSftp.pwd()`+"//"+"new_dir//"+file);
//or
String url = channelSftp.pwd();
String url_m = channelSftp.pwd()+"/"+directory; 
channelSftp.rename(url+file,url_m+file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read your file in inpuStream, then use the function:

```
        put(InputStream src, String dst)
```

doc: https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html

Example:

```
        String fileName = "D:/Folder1/Folder2";
        File initialFile = new File(fileName);
        InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        channelSftp.put(targetStream, "./in/");
```